# From date to tuple Python

Tags: python

I have like input: 12/12/2019
and I want this output: (12,12,2019)
I tried this code but it doesn't work because they consider `"/"` as a division :

```
date= 12/12/2019
date=str(date).split("/")
print(tuple(date))
```

Answer (score 3):

Though your code should work. I also have one more easier code

```
print(tuple(map(int, "12/12/2019".split("/"))))
```

the output is as desired

```
('12', '12', '2019')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date= "12/12/2019"
date=str(date).split("/")
print(tuple(date))
```

Should work. Without the quotes you are sunk, but I assume you are getting these from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> tuple(map(int, "12/12/2019".split("/")))
(12, 12, 2019)
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In order for that to work you need to input the date as a string using "" or '' characters.

```
date = '12/12/2019'
date_split = date.split('/')
date_tuple = tuple(date_split)
print(date_tuple)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
print(tuple("12/12/2019".split("/")))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you created `date` variable as integer instead of string.

If you run

```
date = 12/12/2019
print(type(date))
```

You will get `<type 'int'>`. It means date is an integer number, not string.

If you change `date` to string as shown below, you will get the output you are expecting.

```
date = "12/12/2019"
date=str(date).split("/")
print(tuple(date))
```